# Angular 2 prevent click or enter keyup spam?

Tags: angular, spam-prevention

I build simple chat website with angular 2, it has a login site use socket.io to authenticate, when click button 'login' or press 'enter', it send a message to server with username & password by socket.io emit and server return a message to accept or decline by socket.io emit, too. I'm noob and this is only way I can figure out. I can learn http get solution like many examples on google, but I want something from my brain. I wonder if someone try to spam my server by click on login button or keyup enter to send a login request.And my question is how to prevent someone spam click or keyup enter on login screen?
This is my code from SocketioService:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { Observer } from 'rxjs/Observer';
import * as io from 'socket.io-client';
import Url = require('../data/url');
import 'rxjs/add/operator/debounceTime';

@Injectable()
export class SocketioService {
    private socket: any;
    private urlSocketIo: any

    constructor() {
        this.urlSocketIo = Url.SocketIo;
        this.socket = io(this.urlSocketIo);
    };

    sendMessage(cmd: string, content: string) {
        this.handleMessage(cmd, content).debounceTime(50000).subscribe();
    };

    handleMessage(cmd: string, content: string) {
        let observable = new Observable<any>((observer: Observer<any>) => {
            this.socket.emit(cmd, content);
        });
        return observable;
    };

    receiveMessage(cmd: string) {
        let observable = new Observable<any>((observer: Observer<any>) => {
            this.socket.on(cmd, (Data: any) => {
                observer.next(Data);
            });
            return () => {
                this.socket.disconnect();
            };
        });
        return observable;
    };
};
```

And here LoginComponent:

```
import { Component, OnInit, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

import { SocketioService } from '../_services/socketio.service';
import login = require('../data/login.authenticate');
import { Message } from 'primeng/primeng';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    templateUrl: 'login.component.html',
    providers: [SocketioService]
})

export class LoginComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    connection: any;
    model: any = {
        username: '',
        password: ''
    };
    msgs: Message[] = [];

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private socketioService: SocketioService) { };

    login() {
        let _username: string = this.model.username;
        let _password: string = this.model.password;
        if (_username.length > 0 && _password.length > 0) {
            let _cmd = 'auth';
            let _content = JSON.stringify({ username: _username, password: _password });
            this.socketioService.sendMessage(_cmd, _content);
        } else {
            this.msgs = [];
            this.msgs.push({ severity: 'warn', summary: '', detail: 'Please provide Username & Password!' });
        };
    };

    logout(): void {
        login.authenticated = false;
        this.socketioService.sendMessage('auth', JSON.stringify({ username: 'logout', password: 'logout' }));
    };

    authenticate(): void {
        this.socketioService.receiveMessage('auth').subscribe((Data) => {
            if (Data === 'OK') {
                login.authenticated = true;
                this.router.navigate(['/']);
            } else {
                login.authenticated = false;
                this.msgs = [];
                this.msgs.push({ severity: 'error', summary: '', detail: Data });
            }
        });
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        // reset login status
        this.logout();

        this.authenticate();
    }

    ngOnDestroy() {
        this.connection.unsubscribe();
    }
}
```

and here LoginComponent HTML:

```
<div class="center-page">
    <div class="ui-grid ui-grid-responsive ui-grid-pad ui-fluid">
        <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-grid-col-12 text-center">
                Username:
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-grid-col-12">
                <input (keyup.enter)="login()" type="text" pInputText name="username" [(ngModel)]="model.username" #username="ngModel" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-grid-col-12 text-center">
                Password:
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-grid-col-12">
                <input (keyup.enter)="login()" type="password" pPassword name="password" [(ngModel)]="model.password" #password="ngModel" required />
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-grid-col-12">
                <button pButton type="text" label="Login" (click)='login()'></button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-grid-row">
            <div class="ui-grid-col-12">
                <p-messages [value]="msgs"></p-messages>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you attempted anything to resolve this? Such as applying a debounce to the input?

Comment: I tried search this solution, but still don't understand. Some answers talk about debounce input field, but I'm not dealing with angular form, it's sinple a div with 2 input elements: username, password and a button element, not wraped by form. input elenment handle by enter.keyup event and button handle by click event to send authenticate message to socket.io server.

Answer (score 0):

You can add a debounce time to your angular form.

```
this.loginForm.valueChanges
             .debounceTime(500)
             .distinctUntilChanged()
```

etc

Comment: Thanks for you help, but I'm noob with rxjs. I'm not dealing with angular form, it's sinple a div with 2 input elements: username, password and a button element, not wraped by form. input elenment handle by enter.keyup event and button handle by click event to send authenticate message to socket.io server. I read this method from angular.io, but it seems work with input field. Would you explain more details?